# Generating a list of numbers based on a constraint-step procedure

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, random

I'm trying to generate a list of 8 numbers with the following for code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n2 = np.random.uniform(0.1, 1.5)
c2 = np.random.uniform(4,14)
c3 = np.random.uniform(0.1,2.9)
ic4 = np.random.uniform(0.01,1)
nc4 = np.random.uniform(0.01,1)
ic5 = np.random.uniform(0,0.2)
nc5 = np.random.uniform(0,0.01)

comp_list = []

for i in range(1):
    if n2/c2 <= 0.11:
        comp_list.append(c2)
        comp_list.append(n2)
    if c3/c2 <= 0.26:
        comp_list.append(c3)
    if ic4/c3 <= 0.27:
        comp_list.append(ic4)
    if nc4/ic4 <= 1:
        comp_list.append(nc4)
    if ic5/nc4 <= 0.06:
        comp_list.append(ic5)
    if nc5/ic5 <= 0.25:
        comp_list.append(nc5)

    sum = n2+c2+c3+ic4+nc4+ic5+nc5
    c1 = 100-sum
    comp_list.append(c1)

df = pd.Series(comp_list)

print df
```

However, when i run the code, the amount of numbers outputted is not consistent and can range from 3 to 5. for example, 1 run would give me:

```
0     1.560
1     0.251
2     0.008
3     86.665
```

a second run would give me:

```
0     12.929
1     1.015
2     2.126
3     0.093
4     0.0025
5     83.376
```

I have no idea why the output is not consistent.

Maybe I need to iterate through a random distribution until all the if statements are satisfied? or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Because you are generating random numbers with `np.random.uniform()`?

Comment: I need the random generated number to satisfy the constraint (i.e <=0.2). Is there a way to keep checking if the random number satisfies the constraint? A kind of iteration?

Comment: You haven't explained what you're trying to do or what you expect.

Comment: I want a set of randomly generated numbers to satisfy the constraints i have set. For example, I start with n2 and check if n2/c2 <0.11 ... if it does, it gets appended to the list

Comment: So why do you think your output is wrong?  What did you expect to get?

Comment: I'm expecting a list of 8 numbers... not 3 or 5.

Comment: If you're only adding numbers to the list conditionally, why do you expect that?

Comment: It makes sense that if the condition is not met, the number will not be appended.  But, I'm asking for a solution that will loop again until the condition is met so that the output is 8 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to enclose all that in a while loop. Roll for all your numbers. If they all satisfy your conditions, create the necessary list. As long as one of the conditions isn't satisfied, all numbers will be rerolled.

The reason why you want to reroll all numbers is so that they are all independent of each other. For example, `c2` is involved in both `n2/c2` and `c3/c2`. If `n2/c2` is satisfied and you keep those two numbers, the values of `c3` you can have in order to satisfy the condition `c3/c2` are constrained by what you have already chosen for `c2`.

```
import numpy as np

while True:
    n2 = np.random.uniform(0.1, 1.5)
    c2 = np.random.uniform(4,14)
    c3 = np.random.uniform(0.1,2.9)
    ic4 = np.random.uniform(0.01,1)
    nc4 = np.random.uniform(0.01,1)
    ic5 = np.random.uniform(0,0.2)
    nc5 = np.random.uniform(0,0.01)

    if (n2/c2 <= 0.11 and
        c3/c2 <= 0.26 and
        ic4/c3 <= 0.27 and
        nc4/ic4 <= 1 and
        ic5/nc4 <= 0.06 and
        nc5/ic5 <= 0.25):

        comp_list = [n2, c2, c3, ic4, nc4, ic5, nc5]
        comp_list.append(100 - sum(comp_list))
        break
```

**Edit**: In order to generate a list of such lists, iterate this code as many times as necessary and append the result of `comp_list` each time.

```
big_list = []
for _ in range(10):
   # while stuff
   big_list.append(comp_list)
```

If this is something you expect to run in various locations in your code, you may as well put that in a function.

```
def generate_numbers():
    while True:
        ...
    return comp_list
```

And then you can do `big_list = [generate_numbers() for _ in range(10)]`.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. May I ask how I could run the while loop multiple times to get a set of say 10 lists (10 rows in a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Great! this helped a lot!

Comment: @Joey I had a minor mistake in the code. I meant `[generate_numbers() for _ in range(10)]`. I was missing the brackets after generate_numbers, which would not call the function.